# How do I get a variable from a different php file?

Tags: php, json

I have the following code in my `index.php` page:

```
// Write the resulting JSON to a text file
    var jsontext = $('#code-output').text();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'writetxt.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { data: jsontext },
      success: function(result) {
        $('#code-output').hide().fadeIn('slow');
      }
});
```

And this is the contents of `writetxt.php`:

```
// Generating a unique filename using the date and time plus a random 4-digit string
$filename = date("YmdHis-") . rand(1337,9001);

// Making the JSON text file
$jsontext = $_POST["data"];
$fp = fopen("jsontxt/" . $filename . ".txt","w");
fwrite($fp,$jsontext);
fclose($fp);
```

Basically, a new text file is created every time a change is made to the JSON text. How do I access $filename from the `index.php` file?

Comment: Does this mean you want the filename to be returned in the ajax success callback function every time the ajax call is made?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do.

Comment: Then, as I see it, you'll need to return the var value in JSON format, and process it via JS. See reply below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either include the file in the other one

```
require_once('my_file.php');

echo $varFrom_my_file;
```

or set it to a session variable

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['foo'] = "Bar";
```

Then the other file

```
echo $_SESSION['foo'];
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming index.php has some content along with PHP variable? Using include will include that content. Use a session variable to go across pages.

[PHP Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php)

Answer (score 0):

Return the value of $filename as a JSON string

echo json_encode(array('filename'=>$filename);

Then pull it out of the result var

result.filename

(untested)